# postgreSQL: field separated by semicolon

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a field called **client_no_all**:

```
client_no_all 
14521;555555;636582142;
```

I want to separate the values and assign them to **client_no**:

```
client_no
14521 
555555 
636582142
```

Should I use a cursor to loop or pivot?

Comment: pgsql ist not a plsql, so what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query.
The function `string_to_array()` splits a string by a delimiter into an array.
With the function `unnest()` you can expand an array to a set of rows.

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array('1;2;3;4;5', ';')) AS val
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: @RyanNerd you are right just saw the question and had the same problem two days ago so just shared the solution